# Why is the inverse of a bijective linear transformation defined by the inverse of its matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $f$ be a bijective linear transformation. Why does it hold that $A_{f^{-1}} = A^{-1}_f$, where $A_f$ denotes the transformation matrix corresponding to $f$? I can apply the theorem and understand what it says. What I'm looking for is a proof. So far, I understand the following:

1. A function has an inverse iff it is bijective.
2. Every linear transformation $f: V \rightarrow W, x \mapsto f(x)$ with arbitrary vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is defined by a transformation matrix $A$ such that $f: V \rightarrow W, x \mapsto Ax$.

I couldn't find a proof in my lecture notes and don't know where to start doing it myself so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a a basis $B$ of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. For each linear map $f\colon V\longrightarrow V$, let $A_f$ be the matrix of $f$ with respect to the basis $B$. Then, if $g\colon V\longrightarrow V$ is another linear map, you have$$A_{g\circ f}=A_gA_f\quad\text{and}\quad A_{f\circ g}=A_fA_g.$$So, in particular,$$\operatorname{Id}=A_{f^{-1}\circ f}=A_{f^{-1}}A_f\quad\text{and}\quad \operatorname{Id}=A_{f\circ f^{-1}}=A_fA_{f^{-1}}.$$That is$$A_{f^{-1}}=A_f^{\,-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you. Why is $A_{g\circ f}=A_gA_f$ and $ A_{f\circ g}=A_fA_g$? I know that $F_{BA}=F_B\circ F_A$ where $F_{BA}:K^n \rightarrow K^m, x \mapsto (BA)x$, but can't derive the former from the latter.

Comment: You shall find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948502/show-that-multiplication-of-matrices-corresponds-to-composition-of-linear-transf).