# What does it mean to multiply a matrix by matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I want to understand what matrix multiplication means. I understand how to perform it (and some other concepts e.g. scalar), I can solve some problems using this (e.g. N'th Fibonacci number using binary matrix exponentiation), but I don't deeply understand why it works. I know that (in my case) I can think about matrix multiplication just like a way to solve some coding problem and probably it will be enough, but I want to understand it from math perspective (and I have never heard about it before because I'm secondary school student).

Why do we multiply rows by columns? Why not e.g. multiplying numbers at corresponding positions of two matrices?

I read somewhere that it's due to something called `linear map / linear transformation`. As far as I understood this concept, If I have two sets of vectors e.g. $A = \{(x_1, y)\}$ and $B=\{(x_2,y)\}$,$x_1 < 0$ and $x_2 > 0$ and $y \in R$  and function $T: V->W$, then all vectors from `A` will be in `B` domain and other transformations will be applied (defined by function `T`).

But what it means *to linearly transform by matrix*. What rules apply here and is it related to why we multiply matrix by rows and columns and not in other way? I'm looking for really step-by-step answer and maybe some beginner friendly resources where I can study this stuff better.

*As my knowledge about transformations ends with $f(x-p)+q$, I hope this question isn't too dumb.*

Comment: I don't see how $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ are sets of vectors.  Rather consider $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$.  And [matrix multiplication corresponds to composition of linear transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948502/show-that-multiplication-of-matrices-corresponds-to-composition-of-linear-transf)

Comment: I edited it. I meant something like vectors from left-side of Cartesian plane will be placed at right-side. Is it good now?

Comment: Do you know what a linear combination of some vectors is?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is function composition for linear maps.

Comment: @paw88789 I know how to perform basics operations on vectors, and how to transform functions using vectors like `[p, q]`, but I have never heard about linear combination :/

Comment: Matrix multiplication corresponds to composition of certain types of functions with respect to a chosen set of basis vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer from the pragmatic point of view of matrices as ways to encode linear transformations of variables. Suppose you have real variables $x_1, \dots, x_m$. Suppose you have another set of real variables $y_1, \dots, y_n$ related to $x_1, \dots, x_m$ by
$$y_i = \sum_{j = 1}^{m}a_{ij}x_j.$$
A handy notation for the vector $y$ is $y = Ax$. Now you might have another set of real variables $z_1, \dots, z_p$ related to $y_1, \dots, y_n$ by
$$z_i = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}b_{ij}y_j,$$
that is, $z = By$. Then we can relate $z$ to $x$ by
$$z_{i} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}b_{ij}y_j = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{m}b_{ij}a_{jk}x_k.$$
Thus $z = BAx$, where $(BA)_{ik} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{m}b_{ij}a_{jk}$. So the combined effect of using $A$ then $B$ is the same as using $BA$.